# Questions regarding changing vehicle speed in SUMO through OMNet++ TraCI

Tags: performance, omnet++

I am currently using SUMO-0.19.0 veins-3.0 and OMNet++-4.6.

I have been doing research online about how to change the vehicle's speed through the ini file in OMNet, my goal is to test how different vehicle speed can affect the broadcast. I am able to change the broadcast interval using iteration, and I am able to change the vehicle speed in the .rou file and .net file one at a time.

However, my problem is I want to use iteration in OMNet++ ini file to change the vehicle speed and acceleration to accelerate the simulation process, but I don't know how.

I have checked the link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/Cy1Slhx9h1U, but I still don't know where to use setSpeed, not to mention how to use iteration on changing the vehicle speed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The mentioned Mailing List already shows the answer - you have to provide a function in Veins to set the speed. Then you can add it as a parameter to a .ned file and use it via the omnetpp.ini. See the documentation [here](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec126).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, since I'm new to this, I still don't understand how to provide a function in Veins to set the speed, do I need to edit the TraCIDemo11p.cc or TraCIMobility.cc to add that function?

Comment: The function is already there in [`TraCICommandInterface.h`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h). You just have to use it.

Comment: So where should I call the function? which file are we talking about exactly? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that you can provide a example for calling the functions in TraCICommandInterface.h? I have been trying to use the TraCIDemoRSU11p.ned as an example, but I have failed.

Comment: Here is the code for .ned I have for now, simple TraCICommandInterface
{
    parameters:
        @class(Veins::TraCICommandInterface);
    int setSpeed = default(0,40);
}

Comment: And if the .ned is ok, how should I call the TraCICommandInterface in ini file? With mobility, the original code just use *.node[*].mobilityType = "TraCIMobility", how do you suggest I should proceed with it? Thank you so much for everything

Comment: I added a answer to the question which solves the problem in a more elegant way than my previous recommendation. I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

To have runs with different vehicle speeds it is best to configure a run for every needed speed in SUMO.

To do this you have to create additional `.rou.xml` files with various speeds. How this can be achieved is described in detail in the [SUMO Wiki](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes#Vehicles_and_Routes). Basically, every `.rou.xml` has to have its own value for `maxSpeed`.

Afterwards make sure to load the correct `.sumo.cfg` via the `.launchd.xml`in your `omnetpp.ini`. You can configure OMNeT++ to make a run for various configurations as shown in the [OMNeT++ Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec341).

Comment: Then that would mean I would need to create multiple .rou.xml files, as well as multiple .lauchd.xml and omnetpp.ini files. What I am trying to do is be able to run all different speed profile in one omnetpp.ini files using iteration, so that I don't need to waste time clicking different ini files every time. Any thoughts on that? Thanks

Comment: You need multiple `.rou.xml` files and multiple `.launchd.xml` files but you need only one `omnetpp.ini`. Please have a look at the above linked OMNeT++ manual which describes how to run multiple simulations just via the `.ini` files.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the speed of the vehicles could be changed from the .net.xml file. the only problem is you have to change the speed separately for all the vehicles. the easiest way for that could be changing the speed of the group of vehicles like a group of cars have been classified as  , u can replace the speed with any speed of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using traci interface, you can set any individualy vehicle speed from the next timestep using the command

```
traci.vehicle.setSpeed(vehId, desiredspeed)
```